# Order of the elements in $Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

What are the orders of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$? If $n$ is prime then 0 has order 1 and the rest order $n$. If $a|n$ then $a$ has order $n/a$, and if $a$ is prime then it has order $n$. So are the orders of the elements divisors of n?
Say, we take $\mathbb{Z}_{120}$. Are the orders appearing the divisors of 120?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Prove $o(a)=\dfrac n{a\wedge n}$ $\quad(a\wedge n$ is a standard short notation for $\gcd(a,n)$).

And, yes, in a  cyclic group of order $n$, and any divisor $d$ of $n$, there exists an element of order $d$. Furthermore, the generated subgroup is unique.

Comment: What does the ^ symbol stand for?

Comment: $a\wedge n=\gcd(a,n)$.

Comment: Well, actually, $a\land n$ denotes $\max(a, n)$.  Maybe stick to $\gcd$ when you mean $\gcd$.

Comment: The meaning of $\wedge$  depends on the context. For me, it has the advantage of being shorter to type in formulae.

Comment: When it comes to typing \gcd(a, n), versus a \wedge n, (there's only a difference of one key stroke), this is a situation where had you started with $\gcd$, the OP wouldn't have subsequently needed to ask you, and I wouldn't have to had ask you to say what you mean.  Net deficit of work.

Comment: *In parctise*, it's shorter, and does not depend on the language in which you type.  The reason for this notation is the g.c.d. is the *least upper bound* of $a$ and $n$ for the divisibility relation.